how to check an attribut which is different
I have an attribute which is data-allocation.
I would like to select the locator for which this locator is different to 0
On the code is
data-allocation="0"

On playwiright, the equal works
await page.locator.click("div[data-allocation ='0']")

but I don't know how to write different. i try "!=" or "==" and it doesn't work.
So, how to say to click on locator for which one attribute is different ?

Can you provide more context, possibly the actual page and your goal? This is entirely possible, but not a pattern you typically need often, so there's probably a better way to achieve whatever your underlying goal is.

This question is similar to: Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class or attribute?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You would just do: div[data-allocation]:not([data-allocation="0"])

You are looking for the :not() pseudo class. you can match elements that do not match a list of selectors.
Docs here
